How to embed SwiftData model container in a custom file package document type
I have done a lot of research on this but am not able to come up with a workable solution to this problem. My knowledge and experience in Swift and SwiftUI/SwiftData/AppKit/UIKit is limited so I am probably not seeing the problem correctly to come up with a solution.
Background:
I am trying to make an universal app on macOS/iOS that organizes media (image/video/pdf); think of its functionality like Apple's Photos app. So for my app document type, I would have my custom file package and within the package folder, there would be a SwiftData model container file and folders to hold user media.
Approaches taken:

DocumentGroup with SwiftData model then write directly into the file package

In my App scene, I create document by having DocumentGroup(editing: .customDocument, migrationPlan: CustomMigrationPlan.self). This will create a document with a model container with my SwiftData model. And when I need to add media files into the document, I get the URL of the document, then use FileManager to write the file into the desired folder in the document. The result is that the media file is saved in the file package but then the SwiftData container is corrupted (all model data is reset to empty.)
I am now trying to:

DocumentGroup with custom file package then try to embed SwiftData container

In my current approach, I would create a document by having DocumentGroup(newDocument: CustomFileDocument()). I have custom FileDocument and FileWrapper. But the problem is I don't know how to embed a SwiftData container into my FileDocument. Is it possible to create a SwiftData model container when my FilerWrapper initialize? I can't figure out how to do this.
Can anyone please advice on how I should accomplish this? Or if maybe I am looking at this problem wrongly? Do I need to use AppKit/UIKit with Core Data because it's currently not possible with SwiftUI/SwiftData?
Thank you so much for reading and any input is greatly appreciated.

You can use ModelDocument for that. And there is a sample Building a document-based app using SwiftData and a video Build an app with SwiftData (WWDC 2023).
e.g.
 @main
 struct Todo: App {
     var body: some Scene {
         DocumentGroup(editing: TodoItem.self, contentType: .todoItem) {
             ContentView()
         }
     }
 }


 struct ContentView: View {
     @Query var items: [TodoItem]


         var body: some View {
             List {
                 ForEach(items) { item in
                     @Bindable var item = item
                     Toggle(item.text, isOn: $item.isDone)
                 }
              }
         }
 }


 @Model
 final class TodoItem {
     var created: Date
     var text: String
     var isDone = false
 }


 extension UTType {
     static var todoItem = UTType(exportedAs: "com.myApp.todoItem")
 }


From: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/documentgroup/init(editing:contenttype:editor:preparedocument:)-9ents
The problem you will probably face is the document UI is designed for opening different files rather than always the same library file. You should also probably test that Swift Data doesn't break if the file is moved while open.

Thank you very much. By using your scene initializer, DocumentGroup(editing: Card.self, contentType: <#UTType#>), instead of DocumentGroup(editing: <#UTType#>, migrationPlan: <#SchemaMigrationPlan#>), I was able to write into the document file. You have been a great help. Thank you.

Great, in case it helps I added a bigger sample I just found.
